# how to break foreach loop - array index

Tags: php, arrays

My array which is dynamic, formed as

```
$exam = explode(',',$row['exam']);
```

For example result is:

```
$exam = array("First-Term","Second-Term", "Third-Term");
```

We can get index and value as this

```
foreach (array_values($exam) as $i => $value) {
  echo "$i: $valuen";
  echo "//And its mark";
}
```

But, how can I break loop to each index. I have to fetch as follow

```
First-Term
//And its mark

Second-Term
// And its mark

Third-Term
// And its mark
```

But while using foreach loop, I am getting

```
First-Term
Second-Term
Third-Term
//And its mark
//And its mark
//And its mark
```

How to break loop to each index, after that we use same code in every index. I'm simply try to assign each marks to each term

```
$exam[0]{
    //here is $value
    //rest of the code, same code to every index
}

$exam[1]{
    //here is $value
    //rest of the code, same code to every index
}

$exam[2]{
    //here is $value
    //rest of the code, same code to every index
}

$exam[...]{
    //
}
```

Comment: Read for loop http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Can you give a little more background to what you want the code to do? I don't understand why you would want to beak out of the loop at each index, if you want to execute the same piece of code for each item in the `$exam` array.

Comment: ...wait, do you mean that there is some code that is unique for each term, and some code that is the same for all terms?

Comment: @MarijnvanVliet, same code for every term. Please understand as this. I have to fetch `First term -> Math`, `Second term-> Math`, But I am getting `First term Second Term -> Math Math`

Comment: @AnandHmt, can you give some real example instead of `// code`,`// here`? From a first look, it just looks like echoing info with extra line breaks.

Comment: @Rafael Let me clarify, I'll post real example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make two arrays for `team` and `marks` and then parse these two arrays in the same `foreach` loop like this

```
$team = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd' );
$marks = array('1', '2', '3', '4' );

foreach(array_combine($team, $marks) as $t => $m) {
    echo $t . "<br>" .$m . "<br><br>"; //$t for team and m for marks
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

In this way you can parse your different data in a paralell way

Comment: careful! `if($i = 0)` will assign 0 to `$i`. Did you mean `if($i == 0)`?

Comment: @MarijnvanVliet Ohh. Sorry, It was a typo error. I was in rush

Comment: @ZainFarooq, array is dynamic, so it is not possible to apply rule to each index. how to address this issue ?

Comment: But in question you made a static array

Comment: but now `$i == $counter` will always evaluate to `TRUE`. Why have the `if`-statement in the first place?

Comment: Why need another array to print 1 => First-Term, you can use this as: echo ($i+1)."=>".$value."<br>";

Comment: @maruf I don't know what did you mean here

Comment: @AnandHmt Whats problem in my answer now?

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of what you are doing, you are using two foreach loops with different output...

This one:

```
$exam = array("First-Term","Second-Term", "Third-Term");

foreach (array_values($exam) as $i => $value) {
    echo "{$value}<br>";
    echo "// And its mark<br><br>";
}
```

Will output this:

```
First-Term
//And its mark

Second-Term
// And its mark

Third-Term
// And its mark
```

While this loop:

```
$exam = array("First-Term","Second-Term", "Third-Term");

foreach (array_values($exam) as $i => $value) {
    echo "{$value}<br>";
}
foreach (array_values($exam) as $i => $value) {
    echo "// And its mark<br>";
}
```

Will output this:

```
First-Term
Second-Term
Third-Term
// And its mark
// And its mark
// And its mark
```

Will update this answer once I have more details.
Code tested: https://3v4l.org/RDvYN

Answer (score -1):

I would build an array with everything in place and then start to display it:

```js
$exam = array("First-Term","Second-Term", "Third-Term");
$marks = array(1, 2, 3);

$result = array();
foreach (array_values($exam) as $idx => $value) {
    $result[] = array(
         "exam" => $value,
         "mark" => $marks[$idx]
    );
}

foreach ($result as $value) {
    echo $value['exam'] . "\n";
    echo $value['mark'] . "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Click on "Run code snippet". This tool is designed for HTML/CSS/Javascript statements only.

Comment: OK, of course it won't work that way. Just run it on your machine with php.

Comment: If the code is not supposed to work in a code snippet, maybe it should not be in a code snippet, maybe?